# Phonegap caching

Tags: php, caching, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap and I had a few questions about it:

I currently have a working app that connects to the server and asks a password to be able to see the files in there. Now I need a way to find out how I can make it so when you have no internet you can see the files securely. I heard it's possible with caching but I don't know how to do that with PhoneGap.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [local storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_localstorage_localstorage.md.html) to make a copy of the files locally when you *do* have access, and then keep them for viewing off line. It's not caching but it's more reliable anyway. You also need to make either the whole app password protected or just that area.

I make JSON objects from the info I get from the server and then store them locally. I can then retrieve them and parse them as necessary.